# Yahoo import is not working in openinviter

Tags: php, openinviter

I am new to `openinvitor`. I have downloaded PHPizabi 1.9.6. [From Here](http://openinviter.com/download.php) in that I am running example_list.php file using this i am able to get contacts from gmail but i am not able to get contacts from `YAHOO`. I am getting error `"Login failed. Please check the email and password you have provided and try again later !".`

When I am login from [Yahoo](https://login.yahoo.com/) getting login successfully, but not through this plugin.

Can anyone please help me on this?

code for yahoo.plg.php

```
<?php
$_pluginInfo=array(
    'name'=>'Yahoo!',
    'version'=>'1.5.5',
    'description'=>"Get the contacts from a Yahoo! account",
    'base_version'=>'1.8.0',
    'type'=>'email',
    'check_url'=>'http://mail.yahoo.com',
    'requirement'=>'email',
    'allowed_domains'=>array('/(yahoo)/i','/(ymail)/i','/(rocketmail)/i'),
    'imported_details'=>array('first_name','email_1'),
    );
/**
 * Yahoo! Plugin
 * 
 * Imports user's contacts from Yahoo!'s AddressBook
 * 
 * @author OpenInviter
 * @version 1.3.8
 */
class yahoo extends openinviter_base
    {
    private $login_ok=false;
    public $showContacts=true;
    protected $timeout=30;
    public $debug_array=array(
              'initial_get'=>'util.Event.addListener',
              'login_post'=>'window.location.replace',
              'print_page'=>'field[allc]',
              'contacts_file'=>'"'
              );

    /**
     * Login function
     * 
     * Makes all the necessary requests to authenticate
     * the current user to the server.
     * 
     * @param string $user The current user.
     * @param string $pass The password for the current user.
     * @return bool TRUE if the current user was authenticated successfully, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function login($user,$pass)
        {
        $this->resetDebugger();
        $this->service='yahoo';
        $this->service_user='snehalkinekar8@yahoo.com'; //$user;
        $this->service_password='Gajanan@123'; //$pass;
        if (!$this->init()) return false;

        $res=$this->get("https://login.yahoo.com/config/mail?.intl=us&rl=1");
        if ($this->checkResponse('initial_get',$res))
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('initial_get',"https://login.yahoo.com/config/mail?.intl=us&rl=1",'GET');
        else 
        {
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('initial_get',"https://login.yahoo.com/config/mail?.intl=us&rl=1",'GET',false);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();    
            return false;
        }

        $post_elements=$this->getHiddenElements($res);$post_elements["save"]="Sign+In";$post_elements['login']=$user;$post_elements['passwd']=$pass;        
        $res=$this->post("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?",$post_elements,true);      
        if ($this->checkResponse('login_post',$res))
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('login_post',"https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?",'POST',true,$post_elements);
        else 
            {
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('login_post',"https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?",'POST',false,$post_elements);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();    
            return false;
            }       
        $this->login_ok=$this->login_ok="http://address.mail.yahoo.com/?_src=&VPC=print";
        return true;
        }

    /**
     * Get the current user's contacts
     * 
     * Makes all the necesarry requests to import
     * the current user's contacts
     * 
     * @return mixed The array if contacts if importing was successful, FALSE otherwise.
     */ 
    public function getMyContacts()
        {
        if (!$this->login_ok)
            {
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();
            return false;
            }
        else
            $url=$this->login_ok;
        $contacts=array();      
        $res=$this->get($url,true);
        if ($this->checkResponse("print_page",$res))        
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('print_page',"{$url}",'GET');
        else 
            {
            $this->updateDebugBuffer('print_page',"{$url}",'GET',false);
            $this->debugRequest();
            $this->stopPlugin();    
            return false;
            }

        $post_elements=array('VPC'=>'print',
                             'field[allc]'=>1,
                             'field[catid]'=>0,
                             'field[style]'=>'detailed',
                             'submit[action_display]'=>'Display for Printing'
                            );
        $res=$this->post("http://address.mail.yahoo.com/?_src=&VPC=print",$post_elements);
        $emailA=array();$bulk=array();
        $res=str_replace(array('  ','   ',PHP_EOL,"\n","\r\n"),array('','','','',''),$res);
        preg_match_all("#\<tr class\=\"phead\"\>\<td colspan\=\"2\"\>(.+)\<\/tr\>(.+)\<div class\=\"first\"\>\<\/div\>\<div\>\<\/div\>(.+)\<\/div\>#U",$res,$bulk);
        if (!empty($bulk))
            {
            foreach($bulk[1] as $key=>$bulkName)
                {
                $nameFormated=trim(strip_tags($bulkName));
                if (preg_match('/\&nbsp\;\-\&nbsp\;/',$nameFormated)) 
                    {
                    $emailA=explode('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',$nameFormated);
                    if (!empty($emailA[1])) $contacts[$emailA[1].'@yahoo.com']=array('first_name'=>$emailA[0],'email_1'=>$emailA[1].'@yahoo.com');
                    }
                elseif (!empty($bulk[3][$key])) { $email=strip_tags(trim($bulk[3][$key])); $contacts[$email]=array('first_name'=>$nameFormated,'email_1'=>$email); }
                }
            }           
        foreach ($contacts as $email=>$name) if (!$this->isEmail($email)) unset($contacts[$email]);
        return $this->returnContacts($contacts);
        }

    /**
     * Terminate session
     * 
     * Terminates the current user's session,
     * debugs the request and reset's the internal 
     * debudder.
     * 
     * @return bool TRUE if the session was terminated successfully, FALSE otherwise.
     */ 
    public function logout()
        {
        if (!$this->checkSession()) return false;
        $res=$this->get("http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?logout=1&.done=http://address.yahoo.com&.src=ab&.intl=us");        
        $this->debugRequest();
        $this->resetDebugger();
        $this->stopPlugin();
        return true;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Can any one please tell me what is the problem in this openinvitor???

Comment: did you find any solution? is openinviter safe and secure?